# sudo mkdir -p parent/child | Permission Denied

Tags: sudo, mkdir

This seems like such a Day 0 problem. I need to create a 2-level folder structure.

I tried:

```
sudo mkdir parent/child
>>> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘parent/child’: No such file or directory
```

```
sudo mkdir -p parent/child
>>> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘parent’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can I understand the objective? You want to make a directory called “parent” (for example), then create a directory inside “parent” called “child” (for example). Is this correct? Or do you want to make a directory that has a slash in its name? 

Comment: 2 folders, one inside the other

Comment: In what directory are you trying to create parent/child ?

Comment: ... I wonder if it's on a NFS mount with `root_squash` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most file systems do not work in a fashion similar to S3 block storage, making the automatic generation of what appears to be a fully-qualified path an automagical process. Generally, to do what you are attempting to do, a person would perform these actions:

```
mkdir parent
mkdir parent/child
```

However, if you insist on doing this as a one-liner, you can try this:

```
mkdir -p ~/{parent/{child}}
```

What’s nice about this is that you can create multiple directories pretty much simultaneously:

```
mkdir -p ~/{parent/{child1,child2,child3},uncle,aunt,Morty}
```

This will give you lots of directories all at once, so long as you remember `-p` and the curly brackets

Comment: There is no reason I can think of on a regular Linux file system why `mkdir -p foo/bar` would not work. That's the entire point of the GNU `-p` option to `mkdir`. More importantly, if `mkdir -p ~/{parent/{child}}` works, then so does `mkdir -p ~/parent/child` the braces aren't doing anything useful here. In fact, they are breaking things: your command will create a directory called `~/{parent` and a subdirectory in that named `{child}}`. Try it. Brace expansion only works with commas.